# Is there a way of not shifting the column after colspan

Tags: html, html-table

I'm building a sort of calendar application for room reservation.
[Code Here](https://jsfiddle.net/pb1zvomL/)

````
           ```
            <tr class="room">
            <td class="border room-number">1</td>
            <td class="border" colspan="10">
              <div class="prenotazione out--house"><p>Test Out</p></div>
            </td>
            <td class="border" colspan="10">
              <p class="prenotazione twin">TEst Twin</p>
            </td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border" colspan="3">
              <p class="prenotazione suite">Test Suite</p>
            </td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
            <td class="border"></td>
          </tr>```
````

The user will be able to add a name for the reservation and the number of days of the stay.
After that an element will be created on the <td> where the user clicked with the attribute colspan="x" where x is the number of days for the stay.

The issue is that when this happen, the others <td> elements are shifter on the right side exiting the layout of 31 days.

What i want to happen is no shifting on right side or enclosing everything in another container with a set width where after the 31th nothing will overflow.